# How to pass a CURL url in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I don't know much about CURL, I am working on a project and I am using Twilio for messaging platform.
I need help in retrieving the Messages using CURL and API as given in the Documentation in the Twilio account.

This is the CURL URL, I don't know how to use it in PHP 
please help me in this

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC7cff9e2b7447839017344789f6c18277b/Messages.json?From=%2B12345678' -u AC7cff9e2b74478390173447812f6c18277b:1362b9344ed874478390173447819d6f424
```

the above is my curl how I can pass it in PHP. I just need that help in passing the above URL in PHP and I need the response in JSON. 
this is my image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUMS6.jpg

Comment: can you send me the page, it this was a duplicate question i tried to found out but was not able to find it.

Comment: Why not use the Twilio PHP SDK to make this all easier? https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php

Comment: thanx for the help @ceejayoz I got help from both the library and also from this URL https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/  thanx every one again for the help.